# ASP MVC Manipulate model data based on database rows for a form in the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite stuck with ASP MVC Model's, Now I understand how to create a simple model so I could set some values like this:

```
namespace build_01.Models
{
    public class NewBooking
    {
        public int bookingID { get; set; }
        public string bookingName { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is have a Model that has all the bookingNames for example such as:

```
namespace build_01.Models
    {
        public class BookingNames
        {
            public string administrator { get; set; }
            public string normal { get; set; }
            public string user { get; set; }
         }
    }
```

However, what I would like to do is get this data from a database, for example I could have adminsistrator, normal, user, superuser, banned or whatever I like but the idea is that this information in the database can be changed. The bookingNames can be added, edited or deleted.

So let's say I just added superuser and banned to the database my model would now look like this for when I send it to the view and submit a form from the view to send to the `HTTPPOST` controller:

```
namespace build_01.Models
        {
            public class BookingNames
            {
                public string administrator { get; set; }
                public string normal { get; set; }
                public string user { get; set; }
                public string superuser { get; set; }
                public string banned { get; set; }
             }
        }
```

In my view I'm basically making checkboxes based on this information however I need to be able to set and get the values in a model so I can access them in my `HTTPOST` controller.

Now i've had a look at the Entity Framework but that doesn't seem to be what I want.

Is it possible to be able to create a model with the actual rows or even a column from  a row in order to send it to the view to create a form for those columns so that I can return the values to the `HTTPPOST` in order to input data into a row in a table?

If so how can I approach this?

Comment: You question makes no sense. Why do you think EF wont help? Why would you have a class `BookingNames` where you have a property for each type of user. When ever a user was added or deleted, your would need to shut down, update the model, recompile the app and start again.

Comment: This is the problem. I think it's better to not use them in the model and just handle it with the POST data.

Comment: You haven't really explained what the issue is, but best guess is that you need to get a collection of existing booking names from the database and use it in a drop down list to assign a booking name when you create a `NewBooking`?